# Is correct to use the indefinite article before the word "reeducation" in this context?

Tags: articles

Here it goes:

> Out attidute towards nutrition has been wrong in the past, so we need (**a**) reeducation on it.

Is the use of the article necessary in that context, if not, then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While **education** can be uncountable or singular, or occasionally even countable, **reeducation** is almost always a mass noun. Thus, an article would be inappropriate.

Even without it, the use of the noun form there is not quite natural to my ears. I would use the verb instead:

> Our attitude towards nutrition has been wrong in the past, so we need **reeducating** about it.

To be honest, I'm not sure I could explain why.